# Как сделать определение местоположения через API Яндекс или Google карт?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Нужно сделать маленький блок с картой, чтобы при входе пользователя на сайт карта определяла его местоположение и показывала его на карте.

Весь Интернет просмотрел,а результат не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы видимо по разным интернетам лазим....

- [HTML5 Geolocation with Google, Yandex, Bing, OSM](http://webmap-blog.ru/obzors/ispolzuem-html5-geolocation-api),
- [Яндекс АПИ](http://ymapsapi.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=438) (см ответы)

Comment: я вот такой штукой пользуюсь ибо можно любые карты подключать [leafletjs][1] 

[http://leafletjs.com/][1]